# The smallest free number - divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, haskell, divide-and-conquer

I'm reading a book *Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design*. Tried implementing the divide and conquer solution for *smallest free number* problem.

```
minfree xs = minfrom 0 (length xs) xs

minfrom a 0 _  = a
minfrom a n xs = if m == b - a
                    then minfrom b (n-m) vs
                    else minfrom a (m)   us
    where b = a + 1 + (n `div` 2)
          (us,vs) = partition (<b) xs
          m = length us
```

But this one works no faster than the solution that one might call "naive" solution. Which is

```
import Data.List ((\\))
minfree' = head . (\\) [0..]
```

I don't know why this is like this, what's wrong with the divide and conquer algorithm and how to improve it.

Tried using `BangPatterns`, implementing the version of `partition` that also returns first list's length in the tuple, so it eliminates additional traversal for `m =length us`. None of them made improvement.

First one takes more than 5 seconds, whereas second one does it almost instantly in *ghci* on input `[0..9999999]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have pathological input on which `head . (\\) [0..]` performs in O(N) time. `\\` is defined as [follows](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html):

```
(\\) =  foldl (flip delete)
```

`delete x xs` is an O(N) operation that removes the first `x` from `xs`. `foldl (flip delete) xs ys` deletes all elements of `ys` from `xs` one by one.

In `[0..] \\ [0..9999999]`, we always find the next element to be deleted at the head of the list, so the result can be evaluated in linear time.

If you instead type `minfree' (reverse [0..9999999])` into GHCi, that takes quadratic time and you find that it pretty much never finishes.

The divide-and-conquer algorithm on the other hand would not slow down on the reversed input.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that `minfree` works on unordered list, but `minfree` only works fast on ordered list.